# jQuery hover first and hover second

Tags: jquery

When I hover on the `first`, then it will show `Second`.

If I then hover to `Second`, `Second` shall remain show, else hide `Second`.

My problem is in between hover `first` and hover `Second` it get too fast hiding the `Second`.

How do I delay the `$(".second").hide("slow" );` before I hover to `second`?

```
  $(".first").hover(
    function(){
      $(".second").show();
    },
    function(){
      $(".second").hide("slow" );
    }
  );

 $(".second").hover(
   function(){
     $(".second").show();
   },
   function(){
    $(".second").hide("slow" );
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a timer using `setTimeout()`

```
var $second = $(".second");
$(".first").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout($second.data('timer'));
    $second.stop(true, true).show();
}, function () {
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $second.stop(true, true).hide("slow");
    }, 200);
    $second.data('timer', timer);
});

$(".second").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout($second.data('timer'))
    $second.stop(true, true).show();
}, function () {
    $second.stop(true, true).hide("slow");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9w285/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
$( "#book" ).hide( "slow", function() {
alert( "Animation complete." );
});
});
```